# how do I create a large vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

How do i allocate a vector with 1042 empty indexes?
Will the storage for it be lazily allocated?
like this

```
(def a (array-creation-function 1042))
(def b (assoc a 1041 42))
(b 1041) 
--> 42
```

Comment: I'm looking to create a persistent clojure vector, not a java array

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that vectors are not sparse so you must specify a value for each index when you create the vector. The easiest way seems to be to call (vec  ) on a sequence.

```
(vec (repeat 1042 nil))
```

These values are not created lazily it seems.

Comment: this requires recent version of clojure to provide the 2 argument repeat

Comment: these days (2012) this is the right answer - you should mark yourself correct, arthur.

Comment: i'll take your word on that :)

Comment: If you're looking for a `LazySeq`, `(repeat 1024 nil)` should return just that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want something that's not lazy but which avoids some overhead, you can do:

```
(vec (make-array Object 1024))
```

Note, `assoc` does not alter a vector, it returns a new vector with one of the values changed.  Vectors are immutable.  Your code will never work as posted.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, i edited the question to store the array returned by assoc

Comment: `make-array` returns a Java array, but wrapping it in `vec` makes it into a Clojure vector.

Answer (score 5):

If your data is that sparse, then consider using an empty map instead of a vector.... then you get an unbounded number of lazily allocated empty indexes for free!

```
(def a {})
(def b (assoc a 1041 42))
(b 1041) 
--> 42
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(apply vector (take 1024 (repeat nil)))
```

... is lazy

Comment: Are you sure this is lazy? Although (take 1024 (repeal nil)) is certainly lazy, I think (apply vector ...) will force evaluation of the full sequence.